# Authenticating guest/anonymous users in SPAs

Tags: reactjs, laravel, jwt

I'm creating an ecomerce store using react and laravel. User authentication is theough passport and jwt tokens, yet I was wondering What is the best practice to save the information of the guest users such as cart items, and...
LocalStorage is an option, but what if we need to analyze the data
Another option would be to use cookies and sessions, which in this case violates the restfulness...

Comment: This is very opinion based. My opinion is you can issue tokens to guest users and your client-side can ensure to always send the token on each request. That way you keep a sort of "session" open without a cookie

Comment: is there any implementation out of the box for laravel authentication packages such as passport? How to differentiate between logged in and guest tokens with different privileges. It's strange that I can't find anything about such a thing, as if nobody needs to tack guest users...

Comment: Personally I would just make a new user model, mark the model as a "guest" user and issue a token. Then sweep guest users once a week or something. This will also allow you to easily covert the guest user account to a regular user account if and when the user wants to register to your site but you are right, I don't think there currently is an industry standard way of doing this everyone just does their own thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said; keeping guest shopping cart items and maybe things like favorites(if you have) in LocalStorage is good solution; that way you wont keep your backend busy, and wont lose client's data, lets say, if you want guest to be registered to finalize their purchase.

For analytics part; you can run seperate analytics logic and send it to Google Analytics(If writing your own is too much work). Check out react-ga package. You can track events like scroll positions on items page, how many times an item added to shopping cart etc.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/performance-and-user-tracking-in-react-with-google-analytics/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and great article share, yet I'm not just looking for a solution, I'm looking for the best way to go, some kind of industry standard (best practice) in the field of stateless or stateful tokens.

Comment: Sorry, i dont exactly know industry standards; but pretty sure it depends on the project(needs, company, time, number of visitors..)If its a big company, dont care about costs, maintenance, time and people; i would create a seperate backend for keeping cart items, favourites with guest tokens with my own analytics logic. If its just a regular project and i want to do things easier, would definately go LocalStorage path as dont think guest tokens necessary . Keep data in users browser, i collect item analytics and sent to Google. I did LocalStorage way before in a small boutique shop website.